# Desabilitar ToolStripButton em formulário

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso fazer uma verificação e se for `true`, o botão continua habilitado, caso for `false`, o botão deve ser desabilitado...

Como que eu poderia fazer isso ?

Ate agora só tenho o if, pois não sei como fazer isso:

```
if(true)
{
    //aqui faz minha verificações
}
else
{
   //aqui faria com que o botão fosse desabilitado 
}
```

Existe alguma forma fácil de fazer isso ? Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Érik**

```
if(true)
{
    // Habilita
    meuStripButton.Enabled = true;

    // Exibe
    meuStripButton.Available = true;
}
else
{
     // Faz botão ficar cinza (disable)
     meuStripButton.Enabled = false;

     // Faz botão sumir (hide)
     meuStripButton.Available = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A forma mais resumida e reaproveitavél que você poderia fazer isso é da seguinte maneira:

```
var condicao = //minha condicao    
meuStripButton.Enabled = condicao;
meuStripButton.Available = condicao;

if(condicao)
{
//aqui faz suas verificações
}
```